# how to add and save data to an array then in obj c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

So Im doing a little mini project, what Im trying to do is create something similar to a note taking app. What im doing is allowing the user to type in the title of their note in a text field, then adding that to a UITableViewCell, then when they click on that cell it takes them to another view where they can edit their title, save it and then return them to the original view but with a different title then the one they originally entered.

Here are my current issues

1) How do I save the new titles after the app is closed? (When I add a new title then restart the simulator the UITableView is empty)

2) How do I permanently change the UITableViewCell once the user edits the title? (The titles text goes into the text field but when I edit the title and hit save and go back to the original view controller the original title is still there)

Here is my code for the first view controller:

```
#import "TestViewController.h"

@interface TestViewController (){
}

@end

@implementation TestViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"First Note", nil];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



- (IBAction)btn:(id)sender {
    [_array insertObject:self.fld.text atIndex:0];
    [_tableView reloadData];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [_array count];

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil){
        UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

-  (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segue1"]){
        Test1ViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
       Connecter *connectorClass = [[Connecter alloc] init];
        connectorClass.stringToPass = self.array[self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row];
        vc.connectorClass = connectorClass;
    }

}
```

Heres my code for the second view controller:

```
#import "Test1ViewController.h"

@interface Test1ViewController ()

@end

@implementation Test1ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    _label.text = _connectorClass.stringToPass1;
    _textView.text = _connectorClass.stringToPass;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)button1:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue2" sender:self];
}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segue2"]){
    Test2ViewController *vc1 = [segue destinationViewController];
    Connecter *connectorClass = [[Connecter alloc] init];
    connectorClass.stringToPass1 = _textView.text;
    vc1.connectorClass = connectorClass;
    }
}
```

And here is a third view controller I used as a middle man to pass information through from the testviewcontroller to the test1viewcontroller

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Connecter : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) Connecter *connectorClass;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *stringToPass;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *stringToPass1;

@end
```

Comment: Your first issue is about storing the values permanently in local storage. You can use NSUserDefaults or local db for this.

Comment: For second issue, Replace the text field value in array to update the value.

Comment: You need to use local database for storage of your notes...